# Running multiple pods simultaneously takes a lot of time in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, minikube, kubernetes-pod

On the local machine, I am running multiple pods at the same time. It takes a lot of time to complete even though all the pods achieve the running state almost instantly. Internally i am running a docker image (1.8GB) on each pod. When i run pods on serial order, it takes around 12 sec/pod run but running parallely, the time increases exponentially not even at least the same as serial. What could be the probable cause for this?

**EDIT 1**

The operation is really cpu intensive, reaching above 90%. Is there a way to queue pods as they come for cpu resources, so that instead of all slowing down, each of them execute fast in a queue.

Comment: could be related to the schedular

Comment: pods already in the running state @IjazKhan

Comment: yes , but you are saying when you retry the deploymenet again , it takes time for pods to be up and running

Comment: It might be performance related issue. Could you check for CPU / RAM / IO / network bottlenecks during simultaneous start?